# Who should be attributed for the definition of almost disjoint families of true cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$?

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology

- A family $\mathcal{A}$ of infinite subsets of $\omega$ is called
  *almost disjoint* if for any two distinct sets $a, b \in \mathcal{A}$, the intersection $a\cap b$ is finite.
- An almost disjoint family $\mathcal{A}$ is called **of true cardinality**
  $\mathfrak{c}$ if for every $M \subseteq \omega$, the set $\{a\in
     \mathcal{A}:|a \cap M| = \aleph _0\}$ is either finite or it has size
  $\mathfrak{c}$  ($|\mathbb{R}| = \mathfrak{c}$).
- An almost disjoint family $\mathcal{A}$ is called **completely separable** if for each $B\subseteq \omega$ such that the set $\{a\in \mathcal{A}: |a \cap B| = \aleph _0\}$ is infinite, there is some $a \in \mathcal{A}$ with $a \subseteq B$.

The definition of almost disjoint families of true cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$ appears in the article ``completely separable MAD families" by Michael Hrusak and Petr Simon [(Link here)](https://doi.org/10.1016/B978-044452208-5/50019-3) but apparently it's been known in Prague since the 70's or 80's.

Almost disjoint families of true cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$ **are related** with completely separable almost disjoint families (which were introduced by Hechler in 1971 in *Classifying almost-disjoint families with applications to* $\beta N - N$, Israel J. Math. 10 (1971), 413-432) as follows:

1. Every completely separable almost disjoint family is of true cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$.
2. Given an almost disjoint family is of true cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$, it is possible to build a completely separable almost disjoint family.

**Question:** Who should be attributed for the definition of almost disjoint families of true cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$?